# White & red mould/fungus growing on my tree

Tags: trees, diagnosis, mold

I've just noticed these horrible white/red mould patches on my tree. I'm in the UK, it is winter here.  Could someone please tell me what it is and how do I get rid of it.  The tree is above 25ft tall and close to the house, it's been here with me for 20+ years has beautiful pink blossom in spring. I don't want it dying and falling on the house. Thanks for your help
Seems to be white patches about 6 inches long with red on the edges
The tree is not evergreen and has red leaves

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a few photos? It’s very hard to answer based on a verbal description alone. You can always [edit] your post and the [tour] and the [help], especially [ask], should explain more.

Comment: Photo or two, but otherwise, do you know what tree it actually is and is the red/white mould on trunk, branches or any leaves (if its evergreen)?

Comment: Hello Andi, to add photos, click the edit link. There is the text box where you wrote the details to your question, above what you wrote detail are icons.  The sixth icon from the left, if you scroll over it you will see the words image.  click that icon.  At that point you click the 'browse' link. Find your image and select, then add picture.   At this point you should have your pictures uploaded.  Good luck